# Autocomplete popup automatically displaying in only one type of file. In others, it only displays when you hit the tab key

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've created this autocomplete file, and it works:

```
{
    "scope": "source, text",

    "completions":
    [
       {    "trigger": "load: {% load ... %}", "contents": "{% load ${1:static} %}$0" },
       {    "trigger": "call: {% ... %} (call)", "contents": "{% $1 %}$0" },
       {    "trigger": "comment: {% comment %}...{% endcomment%}", "contents": "{% comment %}\n\t$0\n{% endcomment %}\n" },
       {    "trigger": "lcm: {# ... #} (line comment)", "contents": "{# $0 #}" },
       {    "trigger": "if: {% if %}...{% endif %} ", "contents": "{% if  $1 %}\n\t$0\n{% endif %}\n" },
       {    "trigger": "ife: {% if %}...{% else %}...{% endif %}", "contents": "{% if  $1 %}$2{% else %}$3{% endif %}$0" },
       {    "trigger": "ife: {% if %}\\n...\\n{% else %}...{% endif %}", "contents": "{% if  $1 %}\n\t$0\n{% else %}\n{% endif %}\n" },
       {    "trigger": "url: {% url '...' %}", "contents": "{% url '$1' %}$0" },
       {    "trigger": "extends: {% extends '...' %}", "contents": "{% extends '${1:base.html}' %}$0" },
       {    "trigger": "var: {{ ... }}", "contents": "{{ $1 }}$0" },
       {    "trigger": "block: {% block ... %}...{% endblock %}", "contents": "{% block $1 %}$0{% endblock %}" },
       {    "trigger": "block: {% block ... %}\\n...\\n{% endblock %}", "contents": "{% block $1 %}\n$0\n{% endblock %}" },
       {    "trigger": "for: {% for ... in ... %}...{% endfor %}", "contents": "{% for  $1 in $2 %}\n\t$0\n{% endfor %}" }
    ]
}
```

However, the popup is only *automatically* showing up when I try to use it in *this* file:

[image: screenshot]

When in an HTML, txt, or py file, however (at least those are the three I tested so far), although the snippet expands properly when you hit <kbd>tab</kbd> (the trigger key), the popup dialog does not display *unless and until* you hit the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

How do I get the popup to automatically display in these other types of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your user preferences and add the text scope (e.g. `text` or `text.html`) to the `auto_complete_selector` setting

Comment: That's it! I'm taking a deep dive into Sublime Text, after using TextPad for fifteen years. Awesome stuff, but it's not for the feint of heart. Thank you.